# Array of custom types a Alamofire parameter: 'Invalid type in JSON write

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

I am trying to inline an array of custom types into a dir - as parameter to Alamofire. Alamofire fails with `'Invalid type in JSON write` in `ParameterEncoding.swift: Line142`

```
case .JSON:
    do {
        let options = NSJSONWritingOptions()
        let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: options) //  'Invalid type in JSON write
```

MyClass

```
class MyClass{
    var name: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
}
```

This gives the error:

```
class MyParameters{

    var MyClasses: [MyClass] = []

    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]{
        get {
            return [
                "myclasses": self.MyClasses,
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

Tried this [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230856/what-is-the-more-elegant-way-to-serialize-my-own-objects-with-arrays-in-swift):

```
class MyClass{
    var name: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
}


class MyParameters{

    var MyClasses: [MyClass] = []

    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]{
        get {
            return [
                "myclasses": self.MyClasses.map({$0.name}),
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to map what properties you want to be returned.

Comment: Just name and address?